# await 1, what is it good for?

Tags: javascript

In the postgres node module I stumbled over the following code:

```
async handle() {
  !this.executed && (this.executed = true) && await 1 && this.handler(this)
}
```

I don't understand the `await 1`-part.

Can someone explain what is it good for?

Comment: Maybe async function without await throws some lint errors?

Comment: `await 1` simply returns 1  which equals to true and I am curious as well

Comment: I think that by using that `await` you are executing `this.handler(this)` later (asynchronously) instead of at the same time as the other conditions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using that construct, you can execute the latter function asynchronously, so other pending code in the event loop can execute.

`await` is equivalent to `promise.then`, which causes the resolving function of the promise to be executed in the next tick of the event loop.

```js
function handler(n) {
  console.log('handler', n);
  return true;
}

async function fn() {
  return handler(1) && await 1 && handler(2);
}

console.log('start');
fn();
console.log('end');
```